# Why the presentationLayer of a view doesn't work correctly for me?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, quartz-2d

I want to get the position of a view while it is being animated and moving from one position to another
I tried to use the presentationLayer to get the action location information, 
and tried to print out the location when the UIView is moving.

Here is what is printing out:

`2010-12-08 16:56:50.496 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {45, 45}`

2010-12-08 16:56:50.696 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {45, 45}

2010-12-08 16:56:50.896 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {45, 45}

2010-12-08 16:56:51.096 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {45, 45}

2010-12-08 16:56:51.296 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {45, 45}

2010-12-08 16:56:51.496 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {245, 245} <<----------------------------------------

2010-12-08 16:56:51.696 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {245, 245}

2010-12-08 16:56:51.896 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {245, 245}

2010-12-08 16:56:52.096 Exp[31219:207] point: NSPoint: {245, 245}

notice the arrow, the endpoint is directly printed out without showing points on the path. Can anyone help?

below is my code:

Here's how it is printing:

`-(void)print`

{
 NSLog([NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"point: %@",[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:((CALayer *)[bomb.layer presentationLayer]).position]]);
}

I used a timer to repeatedly print out the animated view "bomb"

`-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder`

{
     if (self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {

```
      bomb = [[BombView alloc]init];
      bomb.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 30, 30);
      bomb.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

      [self addSubview:bomb];

      timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:PRINTINTERVAL // defined to be 0.2

                                         target: self

                                           selector: @selector(print)

                                           userInfo: nil

                                            repeats: YES];               

      [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:      NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

 }

 return self;
```

}

Here's how it is animated:

`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

{

```
 CABasicAnimation * animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

 animation.duration = 10.0;

 animation.delegate = bomb;

 [bomb.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animatePosition"];

 bomb.center = CGPointMake(bomb.center.x+200, bomb.center.y+200);
```

}

when I click, the "bomb" will move and the information printed out should be gradually changing. Because it is moving at such a low speed within 10 seconds.

It moves fine but doesn't print correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're using an `NSTimer` to print the diagnostics. That will execute but perhaps not on the `main` thread, thereby giving you incorrect results.

You could use a timer, but instead have it fire off a method that in turn invokes another method to do your diagnostics. The latter you will execute on the `main` thread using `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

```
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:PRINTINTERVAL // defined to be 0.2

                                         target: self

                                           selector: @selector(timedPrint)

                                           userInfo: nil

                                            repeats: YES];
```

then:

```
- (void)timedPrint
{
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(print)];
}
```

Alternatively, rather that use the `currentRunLoop` use `mainRunLoop`.

If that doesn't resolve the query, then it maybe because of course there are three different layers in the Core Animation architecture; model, presentation, and render. So it maybe that the render layer has changed - as you can see - but the `presentationLayer` has not yet been updated.

There's quite a few related questions on exactly this issue. For example:

[Does the -presentationLayer tell me the in-flight values of an view while it is beeing animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182940/does-the-presentationlayer-tell-me-the-in-flight-values-of-an-view-while-it-is)

[Why does one have to use CALayer's presentationLayer for hit-testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199171/why-does-one-have-to-use-calayers-presentationlayer-for-hit-testing)